# 複数のプロジェクトのgemの管理にbundlerを使用する場合について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

自分のPC上で2つのプロジェクトを開発していて、使ってるrailsのバージョンが同じ場合、それぞれのプロジェクトのディレクトリで同じバージョンのrailsをインストールするのは容量てきに無駄に感じるのですが、どうなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

bundle install実行時に--pathでインストール先を指定しなければ、Ruby本体にインストールされたgemを利用するので、共通で使用可能です。ただ、この場合は実行ユーザがgemでパッケージをインストールできる権限が必要です。rbenvでRuby自体を管理していれば、システムのRubyを汚すことも無いですから、開発環境では--pathは指定しないがいいと思います。

どうしてもRuby本体のgemを使いたくなければ、--pathで共通のディレクトリを絶対パスで指定すれば共通で利用できると思います。